# NodeMCU Power Draw and charging Circuitry

Tags: power, nodemcu, battery

I am planning to build a small wireless keyboard, around 5 buttons and 1 rotary encoder, that will connect via WiFi to my Spotify account. For this project, I was looking at the Node MCU for the board.

I could not find online how much of a battery I will need for this project. I read somewhere that it can draw up to 200mA, so, if I use 4 of these [batteries](https://www.batteryspace.com/lg-lithium-21700-rechargeable-cell-3-63v-5000mah-18-2wh-inr21700-m50---un38-3-passed.aspx) and run them through a [3V3 regulator](https://www.mgsuperlabs.co.in/estore/3.3V-3.6A-Step-Down-Voltage-Regulator-D36V28F3), i should have 20.000mAh, so it should be able to be powered on for at least 100 hours, right? But it will actually be more, as it does not draw 200mA consistently, right?

Should this work? Do you have any other suggestions? Maybe some different batteries?

Also, how should I go about to make it so that it can have an USB C port that can charge the batteries while it is still in use? Sorry if this question is stupid, this is my first real project.

I thought the easiest, cheapest and dumbest solution was to simply try and fit in a regular 28.000mAh power bank and charge the NodeMCU via USB. Is this a decent idea?

Comment: The average power draw would be very dependent on what your NodeMCU does. My experience is that, with the typical IoT applications I use them for (checking and responding to incoming messages, checking buttons or sensors, occasionally sending small amounts of data), the NodeMCU will typically not use more than about 15-20mA on average. This is without putting it in a sleep mode. Your application does not sound very different, unless it requires continuous Wifi traffic. My advice is to measure the power draw and base the battery capacity on that.

Comment: NodeMCU could take up to 180mA when connecting to WiFi, and the esp8266 operated at 3.0-3.6v. you need to make sure that the power supply could provide steady voltage at the sudden surge of current, in many of the early esp8266 dev board design, this was one of the problem that the sudden surge of the current cause voltage drop to below 3.0v even for very short period of time.

Comment: When selecting a voltage regulator for battery-powered application, you need to pay attention to quiescent current, the regular that you linked to has a quiescent current of 2-3mA, meaning that even your NodeMCU is in sleep mode, the regulator itself will drow 2-3mA.

Comment: The regulator that you referred to also has quite a big drop-out voltage (it requires 4.5v input to provide steady 3.3v output). This means that you need two batteries in serial, and this will complicate your charging circuit design. The best is to loop for LDO (Low Dropout) regulator that is designed for battery-power application, it typically have a dropout voltage of around 200-300mV.